# Is it possible to encode javascript object to javascript(rather than json)?

Tags: javascript, json

I know it is possible to convert a JavaScript data object to JSON using JSON.stringify. e.g:

```
var cat = {
    soundString: 'Meow!'
};
```

Then call JSON.stringify(cat) to get `"{"soundString":"Meow!"}"`

I am interested to know if it is possible to have a parallel to this, except instead of turning the JavaScript object into JSON, turn it into a JavaScript string that can be evaluated back to the object.

```
var cat = {
    meow: function() {
        console.log('Meow!');
    }
};
```

I want something that would take the cat object and produce a string `"{meow: function(){console.log('Meow!');}}"`, which can be parsed back using eval.

Can this be accomplished?

Comment: Comes down to "can I serialize a function/getter/setter", right?

Comment: If I can serialize/encode objects containing functions in a way that can be evaluated/deserialize back to the object.

Comment: Non-native functions can be serialized by getting the code of the function using the `toString()` method.  You would either have to invent your own serialization format or use actual Javascript that the other end would run `eval()` on (with the inherent risks of doing that).

Comment: @jfriend00 but can i extract the actual code from the function in the object? If I understand it correctly, it gets compiled to native as soon as you create the object, so restoring the code seems difficult unless you keep a copy of the code alongside the object as you mentioned via custom toString/prototype.getCode.

Comment: Yes, the actual code is still available.  See example: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/21kkegkh/.  Also see MDN on [Function.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString).

Comment: Actually I might be misunderstanding it. you're right, non-native code can be extracted by simply calling toString(). of course objects would yield [object Object] but I can still do a tree traversal to restore the structure myself.

Comment: Did you look at the jsFiddle example I posted for you?

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah that works. There's no way to stringify a whole object though, it seems I would need to traverse its keys myself to restore the evaluatable structure, but it doesn't seem particularly complicated as long as it has no native methods/loops.

Comment: There is no built-in way to turn a whole object (including functions) into a Javascript string.  You can built it yourself.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok I think all i have to do is do JSON.stringify, then do manual work to find the functions/objects and traverse them myself and add them to the string via basic string manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a recursive deep copy method and check for `Array.isArray(item)`

Use `.hasOwnProperty` to avoid the prototype chain

Put additional quotations wherever you want

```
var str = "{"
for (var key in cat) {
    str += key + ":" + cat[key] + ","
}
str = str.substr(0, str.length-1) + "}"
```

Comment: props for using 'for in loop' in exactly where it was meant to! I always forget and just avoid it. And even elegantly removing trailing comma. It solves the problem.

Comment: One note though, need to append '(' and post-append ')' for it to be evaluatable back to the object, but otherwise it works! Here is my final result: http://hastebin.com/eyacegaduq.coffee . Worth noting that it is only one level copy, and isn't exhaustive, but it's cool to know its doable.

Comment: Actually im not even sure that it is a one level copy. it seems to work on multilevel as well. This is really cool!

Comment: no it's not a deep copy, i was just lazy. you will get an issue with embedded objects and arrays. primitives will be missing quotes as well